# Two items per row in ui-bootstrap drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to create dropdown menus for a web app using only angularjs and ui-bootstrap. The menu is similar to what you see in a desktop application, the menus should display a left justified label, and the hotkey reminder text should be right justified, and on the same row.  I'm looking for something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfoSX.jpg

The dropdown buttons also need to be inline elements sitting in a toolbar like configuration.  I'm creating a component for reuse, where each dropdown menu is backed by an object, so the menu widths must scale in a manner that's appropriate to the length of the longest row in the dropdown.

Here are some examples I threw together in plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/RAMgcuVoibeLkHTz4Z3e?p=preview

Example 1.A shows the basic problem.  When the first span in the dropdown list gets to long, it displaces the second span onto the next line.

```
  <span class="example-inline" uib-dropdown>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle>
     A. Autowidth Dropdown
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu>
      <li ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items">
        <a>
          <span style="float:left">{{item.label}}</span>
          <span style="float:right; padding-left: 15px;">{{item.hotkey}}</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </span>
```

Example 2.A has a dropdown that behaves correctly.  Unfortunately, I had to attach the uib-dropdown directive to a block element which means that it won't sit nicely in a toolbar without some extra work.

```
  <span class="example-block" uib-dropdown>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle>
     A. Autowidth Dropdown
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu>
      <li ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items">
        <a>
          <span style="float:left">{{item.label}}</span>
          <span style="float:right; padding-left: 15px;">{{item.hotkey}}</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </span>

.example-block {
  padding: 5px 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

In example 1.D, I put a table in the dropdown menu.  This gives me the behavior that I want but would involve a larger refactor of my pre-existing functionality.

```
  <span class="example-inline" uib-dropdown>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle>
     D. Nowrap Table in Dropdown
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu>
      <table style="white-space: nowrap;" class="dropdown-table">
        <tr  ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items">
          <td style="width:90%">
            {{item.label}}
          </td>
          <td style="width:10%">
            {{item.hotkey}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </ul>
  </span>
```

Is there a cleaner solution here?  I would prefer something like 1.A with a few css tweaks.  I would like to avoid a large refactor if necessary.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One clean solution is using css3 width max-content value

```
.width-max-content {
  width: max-content;
  width: -moz-max-content;
  width: -webkit-max-content;
}
```

Have this class on ul element:

```
<span class="example-inline" uib-dropdown>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle>
     A. Autowidth Dropdown
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu width-max-content" uib-dropdown-menu>
      <li ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items">
        <a>
          <span style="float:left">{{item.label}}</span>
          <span style="float:right; padding-left: 15px;">{{item.hotkey}}</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/gttMX1LZvbbFvcIr1Ysc?p=preview)

Now this works great in chrome, firefox, safari but not in ie, as max-content still not supported in IE (there's no '-ms-max-content' version for IE).

For IE  not so clean way is having margin-right to about maximum width of hotkey strings on anchor tags.

```
.hotkey-margin {
  margin-right: 6em;
}
```

in template:

```
<a class="hotkey-margin">
      <span style="float:left">{{item.label}}</span>
      <span style="float:right; padding-left: 15px;">{{item.hotkey}}</span>
</a>
```

Have it only when dropdown is on inline element.
Also, using both max-content & margin right will cause issue in chrome/moz/safari so add condition like this class will be added only in case of IE. (**Or** you can use this not so clean solution for all browsers & not use max-content width).

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/QLmPiuBpn0AqvCFASFTe?p=preview)

P.S. I'm considering Example 1.A only. Else 1.D i.e. 'Nowrap Table in Dropdown' would be perfect I guess.